# How to trim '\n' from the end of fgets() output

Tags: c

I want to trim newline character from fgets output.

```
while(fgets(buff,1024,fp) ){

    printf("start%send",buff );
```

If there is a line "C is cool", in the file . Then the above code prints.

```
startC is cool
end
```

But I want it to print like

```
 startC is coolend
```

How to do that

Comment: dirty approach `buff[strlen(buff)-1] = 0;`

Comment: @Lashane: That's dangerous in the case where there was no input (EOF) and `strlen(buff)` is 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clean approach

```
#include <string.h>

//...

buff [ strcspn(buff, "\r\n") ] = 0;
```

This will work safely for any flavour of line endings, even if there is none present, and even if the string is empty.

Comment: Nice approach but the comment is misleading and contrary to the rest of the answer.

Comment: @R.. thanks but can you please explain your remark about my comment?

Comment: The comment says *trailing* newlines, but what your code actually does is truncate the string at the first newline (or carriage return) character. `fgets` cannot produce a newline except a trailing one, but there can be plenty of embedded carriage returns.

Comment: @R.. if there are, then you can modify the code to suit. But I don't usually encounter "plenty of embedded carriage returns" in a text file. Even if it's a code source file, in a string literal, they would be escaped.

Comment: Indeed. I don't think it's a major practical concern, just that the comment is unsettling. I +1'd anyway.

Comment: @R.. I tweaked it slightly, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the last character to `'\0'` (null terminator). This is not a good approach because the file may not have always have a newline.

```
buff[strlen(buff) - 1] = '\0';
```

or loop over the char array end replace the `'\n'` with `'\0'`

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < strlen(buff); i++)
{
    if(buff[i] == '\n')
    {
        buff[i] = '\0';
        break;
    }
}
```

or remove the `'\n'` at the end with `strcspn()`:

```
buff[strcspn(buff, "\r\n")] = 0;
```

Comment: The last line read from a file might not have a `newline`, in which case your first example is weak. The `newline` is not added by `fgets`, it is what was in the file.

Comment: True, I only included it because it is an approach that would work for this question. I'll edit to clarify that it's not a good approach.

Comment: If `strlen(buff)` is 0 this produces dangerous undefined behavior.

Comment: that wouldn't happen in this case because fgets would return a null pointer which would cause the while loop condition to fail