# pointers and weird fgets behaviour

Tags: c

This program copies content from a file and transfers all the content except the inputted name. 
This code handles files. The problem i'm having is whenever I take input for `char *name` through `fgets()` the output doesn't work and when the name is for ex: light, the line which has lightdm also gets deleted.

group.txt (original file)

```
systemd-timesync:x:100:102:systemd Time Synchronization,,,:/run/systemd:/bin/false
systemd-network:x:101:103:systemd Network Management,,,:/run/systemd/netif:/bin/false
systemd-resolve:x:102:104:systemd Resolver,,,:/run/systemd/resolve:/bin/false
systemd-bus-proxy:x:103:105:systemd Bus Proxy,,,:/run/systemd:/bin/false
syslog:x:104:108::/home/syslog:/bin/false
_apt:x:105:65534::/nonexistent:/bin/false
messagebus:x:106:110::/var/run/dbus:/bin/false
uuidd:x:107:111::/run/uuidd:/bin/false
lightdm:x:108:114:Light Display Manager:/var/lib/lightdm:/bin/false
whoopsie:x:109:117::/nonexistent:/bin/false
avahi-autoipd:x:110:119:Avahi autoip daemon,,,:/var/lib/avahi-autoipd:/bin/false
avahi:x:111:120:Avahi mDNS daemon,,,:/var/run/avahi-daemon:/bin/false
dnsmasq:x:112:65534:dnsmasq,,,:/var/lib/misc:/bin/false
```

if ex lightdm is inputted

```
systemd-timesync:x:100:102:systemd Time Synchronization,,,:/run/systemd:/bin/false
    systemd-network:x:101:103:systemd Network Management,,,:/run/systemd/netif:/bin/false
    systemd-resolve:x:102:104:systemd Resolver,,,:/run/systemd/resolve:/bin/false
    systemd-bus-proxy:x:103:105:systemd Bus Proxy,,,:/run/systemd:/bin/false
    syslog:x:104:108::/home/syslog:/bin/false
    _apt:x:105:65534::/nonexistent:/bin/false
    messagebus:x:106:110::/var/run/dbus:/bin/false
    uuidd:x:107:111::/run/uuidd:/bin/false
    whoopsie:x:109:117::/nonexistent:/bin/false
    avahi-autoipd:x:110:119:Avahi autoip daemon,,,:/var/lib/avahi-autoipd:/bin/false
    avahi:x:111:120:Avahi mDNS daemon,,,:/var/run/avahi-daemon:/bin/false
    dnsmasq:x:112:65534:dnsmasq,,,:/var/lib/misc:/bin/false
```

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{

    FILE *fold = fopen("D:\\C Codes\\deluser\\PFILE\\group.txt", "r"); // old file
    FILE *fnew = fopen("D:\\C Codes\\deluser\\PFILE\\group1.txt", "w"); // new temp file
    char *name = "lightdm"; // whatever user selected
    char buf[64]; 

    while (fgets(buf, 64, fold)) {

        if (!strstr(buf, name)) {

            fprintf(fnew, "%s", buf);
        }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fopen` can fail, and often does for example if a file does not exist. You absolutely __must__ check if `fopen` fails and acct accordingly.

Comment: the old file definitely exists

Comment: That's not an excuse, change your code and do the checks, to eliminate this red herring. Maybe there is a typo in your code. I've seen it so many times before in other questions.

Comment: Also show a minimal `group.txt` file that allows to reproduce the problem along with the actual and the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

1. for the first issue::

   > The problem i'm having is whenever I take input for char *name through
   >   fgets() the output doesn't work

   It is because `fgets` appends `\n` to the output buffer, you will have to trim it.

   [how-to-trim-n-from-the-end-of-fgets-output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34549703/how-to-trim-n-from-the-end-of-fgets-output)
2. for the second issue.

   `strstr` will match substring and in order to mtch the exact word using `strstr` 
   refer
   [Matching an exact word using in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352846/matching-an-exact-word-using-in-c).

Comment: Although true, I don't see the relevance - OP isn't outputting a newline. It looks as though OP does not realise that `"light"` will be found as a substring of `"lightdm"`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I agree with you, I have updated the answer with relevant link.

Comment: Yes, OTOH the presence of the newline will prevent `strcmp` from finding the exact match for `"light"`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Do you think we should mark this question as duplicate of above answers?

Comment: I think your answer should point out that the newline needs to be removed *and* `strcmp` needs to be used. Of course the newline then needs adding back in the `fprintf`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't think `strcmp` will help here. Can you please recheck the question, OP has added the examples.

Comment: Hmm, OP wants to remove a line that says `"light"` but not one that says `"lightdm"`.

Comment: No I want to remove the line if the name is in the file. In this case `"lightdm"`

Comment: @4shwin_26 yes, 1st. Trim the newline if you are reading search string from stdin. 2. `strstr` will match the substring, thus you need some additional check as suggested by the link provided in the answer.

Comment: No, he doesn't need to trim the final `\n` if he is not going to do more on the lines than to copy them to the output.  Trimming the intput is a question of taste, and he OP doesn't need to implement something that is not required.

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't seem to be incorrect, except that you have reserved very low space for the buffer, and in that case `fgets()` returns what fills the buffer, and then the next call brings you the rest until the new line.  Give more space for the buffer, as you have lines in the files you showed above that are longer than 64 bytes.

As you don't trim the last `\n` character, and produce one yourself (as recommended in some of the comments) you don't see the break, and it seems that `fgets` is dealing with the whole lines.... that's simply not true.... lines longer than 63 chars are divided into two chunks (first of 63 ---plus one more for the `\0` string terminator) and the second with the rest of the line.

You don't post the bad output, but I guess if the line containing the name you want to be filtered out is longer than 63 chars, then the last part is written (in the second run through `fgets()` where it doesn't have anymore the searched string)